# ROC plot in roc.plot is exending axis beyond the ylim and xlim

Tags: r, plot, roc

The following code produces the roc plot below.  It seems to be ignoring the limits I've set on the axis.  How can I get the plot to stop at 0 and 100?

```
roc(rdb$Engramcell,
    rdb$ActivityScore, 
    plot=TRUE, legacy.axes=TRUE, percent=TRUE, 
    plot.window(xlim=c(100, 0),
                ylim=c(0, 100)),
    xlab="False Positive Percentage", ylab="True Postive Percentage", 
    col="firebrick4", lwd=1, print.auc=TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: I'm don't understand your question. The plot axis are already between 0 and 100. What do you mean "stop at 0 and 100"?

Comment: It has continued past 0 and 100, why are there margins around the limits?

Comment: Why does the plots window go past the 0 and 100 mark?

Answer (score 0):

First, you didn't set the limits properly, you should pass `xlim` and `ylim` directly, not a call to `plot.window`.

```
roc(...,
    percent=TRUE, 
    xlim=c(100, 0),
    ylim=c(0, 100)),
    ...)
```

But this wouldn't change your plot. By default, R extends the data range by around 4%. These margins are controlled by the [`xaxs` and `yaxs` graphical parameters](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/graphics/topics/par). Setting them to `"i"` removes the margins:

```
library(pROC)
roc(aSAH$outcome, aSAH$ndka, plot=TRUE, xaxs="i", yaxs="i")
```

[image: A plot with no margin]